# How can I line up/indent function arguments up to (

Tags: vim, indentation

I want to do this in VIM:

```
// before
int DoStuffToSometing(int stuff,
        char action,
        int something);


// after
int DoStuffToSometing(int stuff,
                      char action,
                      int someting);
```

`=%` while being on the matching parenthesis, doesn't work.
How to line up things as shown above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:set cinoptions+=(0` then do the select the content and press `=`.